# Linux command to find a file

Tags: linux, command

If I have a directory School, and have a sub directory Park Tree and within park I have Swing and within swing I have rope and within rope i have a file names cotton.

Is there a linux command that i can type in School that will search through all of my directories and folders to find the cotton file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Find command with the name to search on.  Simple as;

find -name cotton

If you use this command from the School directory if will search all sub directories.

Comment: This is a wrong answer.  The correct one will be `find School -name cotton`.  And that is assuming that you are in the directory that holds your directory `School`.

Comment: If you use this command from the School directory, which is what the OP states, this command works correctly to find a file named Cotton.

Comment: Sorry @KSdev, it does not.  Check the man page.  It requires the `path` prior to the expression.

Comment: find's default path is the current directory(from find --help) so you do not need to include the directory if you are currently in it, which again, the OP states.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

locate -i cotton

it works faster.

the -i for ignore case, you can use

locate -i Cotton | grep School

gets you the directories under School that contains file cotton.

Just a reminder ,do "updatedb" frequently, as the file is searched as an database index in "locate" command.